# Accessing C# unmanaged exports from Delphi application

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, dllexport

I am using Robert Giesecke's [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) to put some methods from a C# class into a DLL. For now, the code is:

```
[DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
{
    return left + right;
}
```

which is the same as Giesecke's sample code, aside from the `CallingConvention` but I've also tried it with `Cdecl`).

I'm trying to access this method in my Delphi VCL WinForms application. I'm following [this article](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_DLLs) that is talking about exporting from a Delphi DLL and using the function in a Delphi console application. I may be wrongfully assuming too many similarities here.

Anyway, there are two notes:

1) Using [GExperts's](http://www.gexperts.org/) PE Information on that DLL (exported from a C# project) lists no exports. Seeing as this tool shows the entry points for the available exports, this to me is red flag #1. I didn't check Dependency Walker.

2) The Delphi article says to add the function declaration, then shows an example. My IDE doesn't like that syntax. This may be an application vs. console difference.

```
const
  TestExportsDLL = 'CS_CallbackTest_Class.dll';
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
...

  private
    function AddIntegers(_a, _b: integer): integer; stdcall; external TestExportsDLL;     
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

I've tried with a few different variations on this. Assuming using `RGiesecke.DllExport` is the best way to do this, why can't I get the Delphi application to compile?

Comment: You've declared a method but you need a standalone function. Move it outside of the class. Except that you will have to add `name 'add'` to the end of the declaration.

Comment: Read the article again. In no case does it indicate you can export a form's method. In fact, the very example you used does not have a `TForm1` in front of its implementation in any of the four examples of its code..

Comment: @Tlama ok, it's outside of `TForm1`'s class. Compiles. When I try to run, I get "The application was unable to start correct (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application." Where does the 'add' go?

@KenWhite that was because the article was referring to a console application. So per @Tlama's suggestion, I've moved it out of `TForm1`'s implementation.

Comment: Try `function AddIntegers(Left, Right: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external TestExportsDLL name 'add';`. That name must be specified because you called your function `AddIntegers` on Delphi side, but you're exporting function called `add` on your C# side.

Comment: @ikathegreat: you did not move it out of `TForm1`'s **implementation**, you moved it out of `TForm1`'s **declaration**. That may sound like nitpicking, but there is a huge difference, and you should learn what it is. You made `AddIntegers` a method of a TForm1 class. It should be a standalone function, as others told you already. Please learn the difference. Read the Delphi (or Object Pascal) language guide that comes in the F1-help for each version of Delphi.

Comment: @ikathegreat: As @TLama said, you must add `name 'add'` because the compiler **can not know** that when you called your function `AddInteger` you actually meant to import a function with a completely different name (`'add'`). So you must explicitly tell it.

Comment: FWIW, On the nuget download page, Robert Giesecke gives the following hint: "You have to set your platform target to either x86, ia64 or x64. AnyCPU assemblies cannot export functions.". Did you explicitly set it to either x86 or x64?

Comment: No, the article referred to neither a console or GUI application when defining the function to export; it referred to a DLL, which is neither of those things. As I said in my last comment, *read the article again*.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to know why the function isn't being exported. You didn't describe the steps you took to make the DLL. UnmanagedExports does work though. Follow the documented steps very carefully. One possible clue can be found in the documentation you linked to:

> The task will only execute when you have selected a specific CPU target (x86, x64, Itanium) in your build option.

Until you get a DLL that exports your function there's not much point continuing to the Pascal code.

Your importing code is confused. An external function has to be declared at unit scope. A complete program to import looks like this:

```
{$apptype console}

const
  dllname = '...'; // replace this with the actual name

function add(left, right: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external dllname;

begin
  Writeln(add(42, 624));
  Readln;
end.
```